# script to select and change font color in a filemaker field on specific records

Tags: applescript

I am trying to create a script in Filemaker, so that when one field contains a specific value it will go to another field, select the text and change that field text color, just on that specific record.  Is there an applescript method to change selected text from one color to another?

(I run a small B&B and am trying to get fields to change to red when the reservation cancelled field is selected.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by applying Conditional Formatting to the text field when in Layout mode; no script required.